# Get drawing area from PictureBox

Tags: c#, picturebox

I've got an issue with a `PictureBox` being different sizes between different resolutions.

I have an image which I need to fit into that `PictureBox`, but I need to know the drawing size of it since I need to do the resize myself (otherwise the system was just way too slow, and I decided to do the resizing manually, which works fine if I know the resolution needed).

I tried `PictureBox.Height / Width`, and `PictureBox.ClientRectangle.Height / Width`, but that values are the same for all resolutions. How do I manage to get the actual drawing size?

The initialization code:

```
            // 
            // PicboxRed
            // 
            this.PicboxRed.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
                        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));

            this.PicboxRed.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DimGray;
            this.PicboxRed.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Center;
            this.PicboxRed.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            this.PicboxRed.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(19, 92);
            this.PicboxRed.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 4, 4, 4);
            this.PicboxRed.Name = "PicboxRed";
            this.PicboxRed.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(852, 840);
            this.PicboxRed.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal;
            this.PicboxRed.TabIndex = 9;
            this.PicboxRed.TabStop = false;
            this.PicboxRed.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.PicboxRed_Click);
            this.PicboxRed.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Picbox_Paint);
```

I understand that this has to do with the Anchors being set, but this allows the PictureBox being well seen with different resolutions. How do I grab that real drawing area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ClientSize property tells you how large it is.  The ClientSizeChanged event tells you when it changes for any reason, including automatic scaling due to the form's AutoScaleMode property.

Comment: Thanks, turns out that it only gets resized when actually displayed, and not after initialization. Afterwards it showed the expected value.

Answer (score 0):

`I tried PictureBox.Height / Width, and PictureBox.ClientRectangle.Height / Width, but that values are the same for all resolutions.`

I think you are looking for dpi settings:

```
int currentDPI = 0;

using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
{
    currentDPI = (int)g.DpiX;    
}
```

This value should change on computers with different resolution and dpi settings.

Or maybe you are interesting in getting the current screen resolution. They might help:

`Rectangle resolution = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;`